# Potential Memory Leak Using High Order Swift functions

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, filter, closures

If I wanted to capture the array that I'm running a filter on inside the closure, that will create a strong reference cycle. Since an array is a value type in swift, I can't capture it as a weak pointer in the capture list inside the closure. What could be a good solution for this?

Example:

```
array.filter{ array.contains($0+2) }
```

In this case, I'm capturing array again hence creating a strong reference cycle, how can we combat this problem?

Note: I'm not asking for a solution to this problem (keeping values that are 2 away from one another), this is just an example. I'm just curious as to how we can tackle this problem.

Comment: You can't have a reference cycle with a non-reference type. Don't assume there is a memory leak. Verify if there is actually a memory leak using Instruments.

Comment: > Reference counting applies only to instances of classes. Structures and enumerations are value types, not reference types, and are not stored and passed by reference.

[from here](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it applies to this problem, but I discovered that having `High order function` uses a `strong self` leading to possible `memory leaks`.

It is very bad because I can do something like `array.filter(byTime)` instead should be used like `array.filter { [weak self] item in return self?.byTime(item) }`